# How to write update stored procedure in webmatrix form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix

Here I write update query in my webmatrix form which run correctly but I want to use a stored procedure in place of query so how can I write that?

```
var UpdateQuery = "UPDATE Reg_tb SET FirstName = @0, LastName = @1, UserName = @2, Password  = @3 WHERE UID = @4";
db.Execute(UpdateQuery, FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password, Userid);
```

Comment: Do you know that SQL CE doesn't support Stored Procedures? Are you using another database server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
var execProc="EXEC ProcName FirstName=@0,LastName=@1,UserName=@2,Password=@3, UID=@4";
  db.Execute(execProc,FirstName,LastName,UserName,Password,Userid);
```